# Convert JSON format to CSV Bash using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

Here is my sample code:

```
[
    {
        "urlString" : "https://www.test.com/products/gift-card",
        "imageUrl" : "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0454/6253/products/dope_mone_850x.jpg?v=1539288792"
    },
    {
        "urlString" : "https://www.test.com/products/gift-card",
        "imageUrl" : "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0454/6253/products/dope_mone_850x.jpg?v=1539288792"
    },
]
```

I want to create a CSV file with the output:

```
https://www.test.com/products/gift-card,https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0454/6253/products/dope_mone_850x.jpg?v=1539288792
https://www.test.com/products/gift-card,https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0454/6253/products/dope_mone_850x.jpg?v=1539288792
```

Header tags are not essential but if they are in the solution thats fine.

thanks for the help!

Comment: Ideally, one would show what you've tried and how the output differed from expectations.

Comment: Also, make sure that even when you trim your JSON down you don't make it invalid. In this case, it doesn't parse on account of an extra comma.

Comment: BTW, you're showing output that doesn't have quotes around the strings. Is that intentional? (*Real* CSV should accept those quotes, and some cases -- like when your keys or values contain literal commas -- even require them; but if you're building for consumption of a different tool, maybe we need to change things a bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jq -r '.[] | [.urlString, .imageUrl] | @csv'
```

See this on jqplay at https://jqplay.org/s/zL6HpSSFw0